# How does kernel_thread_helper pass parameters to kernel thread function using inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, calling-convention

I'm reading about the source code of linux kernel of version 2.6.11 and getting confused about the inline-assembly `kernel_thread_helper` in `arch/i386/kernel/process.c`.

Following is the assembly code. Initially, register `%ebx` stores the address of a function and register `%edx` stores a pointer which is going to be passed to the function.

```c
extern void kernel_thread_helper(void);
__asm__(".section .text\n"
    ".align 4\n"
    "kernel_thread_helper:\n\t"
    "movl %edx,%eax\n\t"
    "pushl %edx\n\t"
    "call *%ebx\n\t"
    "pushl %eax\n\t"
    "call do_exit\n"
    ".previous");
```

I'm wondering:

- Why does this piece of code execute `movl %edx,%eax`? Since `pushl %edx` has pushed the value of `%edx` in stack, the function pointed to by `%ebx` should then retrieve needed parameters from the stack successfully. So is there no need to copy `%edx` to `%eax`?
- I know that when `__attribute__((regparm(3)))` is added in front of a function definition, the function will retrieve parameters in the order `%eax`, `%edx`, `%ecx` and stack. So I'm wondering, is the instruction copying the value in `%edx` to `%eax` designed to be compatible with functions that use this `__attribute__`? Function with such an attribute should retrieve the needed parameters from `%eax` and go on running as well! But this causes a problem: the previously pushed pointer by `pushl %edx` could remain in the stack if no one pops it off.

I'm new to Linux Kernel and maybe misunderstood something. I want to know how these assembly instructions work actually and what's wrong with my guess.

Comment: My guess is, `*%ebx` is `regparm(3)` and `do_exit` is `cdecl`, so `do_exit` will consume the pushed args.

Comment: or `*%ebx` might take more than 3 args, so the last arg is taken by `pushl %edx`.

Comment: You have to check how many arguments `*%ebx` and `do_exit` takes to be sure.

Comment: @xiver77: `cdecl` isn't a thing in Linux.  The default (non-regparm) stack args calling convention for legacy 32-bit code (i386 System V ABI) is called `asmlinkage` in the Linux kernel.  But yeah, that would make some sense.  Doesn't really explain why there's a `mov %edx, %eax` before the first call, though, unless that's maybe covering the case where `*ebx` is regparm *or* asmlinkage, putting the arg in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A comment](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tglx/history.git/tree/arch/i386/kernel/process.c?h=v2.5.0&id=381ab1f538162eb985c9244aa7d56e54315881ab#n496) in an earlier Linux kernel version (v2.5.0) explains this (the `movl` into `eax` [was added in v2.1.131](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/2.1.131/source/arch/i386/kernel/process.c#L487) to really be precise):

```c
int kernel_thread(int (*fn)(void *), void * arg, unsigned long flags)
{
    long retval, d0;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "movl %%esp,%%esi\n\t"
        "int $0x80\n\t"     /* Linux/i386 system call */
        "cmpl %%esp,%%esi\n\t"  /* child or parent? */
        "je 1f\n\t"     /* parent - jump */
        /* Load the argument into eax, and push it.  That way, it does
         * not matter whether the called function is compiled with
         * -mregparm or not.  */
        "movl %4,%%eax\n\t"
        "pushl %%eax\n\t"       
        "call *%5\n\t"      /* call fn */
        "movl %3,%0\n\t"    /* exit */
        "int $0x80\n"
        "1:\t"
        :"=&a" (retval), "=&S" (d0)
        :"0" (__NR_clone), "i" (__NR_exit),
         "r" (arg), "r" (fn),
         "b" (flags | CLONE_VM)
        : "memory");
    return retval;
}
```

So yes, as you suspect, the `movl` into `eax` is exactly to provide compatibility for *both* functions compiled with `-mregparam` or an equivalent `__attribute__` *and* without (i386 System V ABI calling convention, i.e. all parameters on the stack).

> But this causes a problem: the previously pushed pointer by `pushl %edx` could remain in the stack if no one pops it off.

Well, true, but who cares about popping it off if the only thing we are doing right after calling the kernel thread function is `pushl %eax; call do_exit`? Doing `movl %eax, 0(%esp)` would work as well, but if there's enough stack space to run a kernel thread then surely there are 4 bytes to push a register after it returns. Additionally `pushl %eax` is only 1 byte vs 3 for the `movl`, and I'm not sure about latency or throughput of the two, but I don't really think that was a concern in such a piece of code.

Comment: `push %eax` is actually *more* efficient there on modern Intel CPUs than `mov %eax, (%esp)`, not needing a "stack sync" uop because it avoids an explicit use of the stack pointer between a call (which would have returned with a `ret`) and another `call` (which will create a non-zero offset in the stack engine so there's no downside to push itself getting doing that.)  The stack engine is one reason clang prefers `push rax` / `pop rcx` or similar dummy push/pop for stack alignment in 64-bit code instead of sub/add 8 at the top/bottom of functions.